# EMM Wipe device?

Tags: wso2

I have one question regarding removing devices in EMM 1.1.0.

In my scenario device was stolen so we want to wipe whole data on the device and remove it from inventory.
When i click wipe, device is cleared but still exists in inventory... so i click enterprice wipe but device is no more comminication with WSO2 server and device is not removed from inventory.

From other hand:
When i click wipe enterprice device is no more managed from EMM but is not formated and user data can still be accessd on the device...

Is there a posibility to do Both wipe whole data and remove it from EMM?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Enterprise Wipe currently unregisters the device from EMM server and clears the agent's (app) data. Wipe will do a factory reset to the device.

Comment: But how to do both? And i don't see wipe iOS option?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the platform. In iOS it only has enterprise wipe which only wipes out the enterprise portion from your device. For Android its not the case where it has both the options where wipe erase out entire phone data. Anyway in both the cases device will be removed form EMM database and should not get displayed in the  EMM portal.

Comment: Then the function might have been somehow broken or partially executed. Otherwise it should get removed. What device type are you working with? Is it Android or iOS?

Comment: Can be. I didn’t found out why it's nor removing. Maybe someone have a similar problem?

Comment: So far it has worked for me. What type of device type are you talking about? If its iOS it can happen since the enterprise wipe also depends on APNS where it waits for an execution call from APNS server to get the wipe payload executed on the device.

Comment: iOS WIPE and WIPE Enterprive work fine, only Android WIPE don't remove device. when i do WIPE Enterprice on android device it is removed from EMM.